# I'm looking for the right audio amplifier, but am lost in a maze as an unexperienced starter

Tags: amplifier

Firstly thanks for helping out!

The problem I am facing is that I have to power 24 audio exciters (2W max, 8 Ohm) from a microcontroller which is currently 5V but might be switched to 3.3V later on. Currently we use one pin to send a blockwave signal (think of 300Hz) to 24 different digital potentiometer channels (0-10kOhm, I2c controlled, this to set the power of every audio exciter seperately) after which each signal should go through an audio amplifier that is powered externally, finally the signal arives at the audio exciters.

My question here is; what amplifier, or kind of amplifier, do I need? Preferably it should be able to be put on a PCB in the near future so an ic is the best choice. Do i know all info to pick out a good amplifier, and what should I be looking for?

I have tried looking around, however there are so many specs and possibilities that I just get lost every single time. Any advice would be highly appreciated, remarks on the design are also welcome!

Comment: What does an "audio exciter" do, exactly? How do 24 of them operate as a system? What is a "blockwave signal?" Most of what I get from your question is a lot more questions about what you are working on achieving. And there? I've no real clue. Any chance you could write a little more about all this?

Comment: It seems like you need a more than an amplifier:  You need some way to interface the digital potentiometers to the amplifier. You need to mute the amplifier when the potentiometers are signaled. (BTW, why are you using in-band signaling?) Please add some more description to the question, and include links to the products you already have and describe (with a schematic or block diagram) how they are connected.  Also: Doesn't the manufacturer of the Audio Exciter also manufacture compatible amplifiers?

Comment: @jonk I can definitely give some more background info, i was afraid i would give to much.
We're designing a sleeve to put on your arm with 24 audio exciters (type of speaker, driven by a waveform signal). Here all 24 exciters need to be driven independant w.r.t. eachother for their amplitude, but the frequency of the square wave (this is the only thing we're sending them) can be the same for all. Currently we're splitting one signal into 24 channels, then sending it through potentiometers so that we can control their amplitude, after which we need to amplify the signal again for the speaker.

Comment: Something like this  perhaps ? https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/STMicroelectronics/STA309A13TR?qs=5J552fbOmoqOsj9s2GLAdQ%3D%3D

Comment: @Benjamin Interesting. If you are driving "exciters" using only square waves, then there are two things you can vary: the amplitude and the duty cycle. Are you varying one, or both, of these?

Answer (score 0):

it seems like class D audio amplifier chips would be a good choice as at 2W output a class D  amplifier won't need a heatsink